# Flask Social - FACEBOOK_SOCIAL not taking request_token_params argument

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, flask

I am using Flask and Flask-Social to work with a web login using the Facebook API, and I am having some troubles when I ask for permissions.
Basically, I am not capable to ask for other permissions than the default ones.

I have tried with the yaml file, and the python dictionary, and nothing. I cant even find more specifications about this param, so here i am, asking to you.

I have tried this:

```
SOCIAL_FACEBOOK:
    consumer_key: 'key'
    consumer_secret: 'secret'
    request_token_params:
      scope: 'user_location'
```

but it's still taking the default arguments.

Help please guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `settings.py` file, I am able to this:

```
SOCIAL_FACEBOOK = {
    'consumer_key': 'xxx',
    'consumer_secret': 'xxx',
    'request_token_params': {'scope': 'email,publish_actions,user_photos'}
}
```

And it works just fine.

Check if the permissions are not cached on facebook - you should remove the application from App Center and relogin.